# Fused location provider doesnt plot continuous line

Tags: java, android, plot

Can anybody help me with this kind of problem with plotting continuous line between last and current position using fused provider

onLocationChanged method looks like:

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location mylocation) {

    logEvent("onLocationChanged");

    mlastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mCurrentLocation = mylocation;
    plotroute(mylocation);        
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
}
```

and plotroute method:

```
public void plotroute (Location mylocation){
logEvent("------------Plotting route---------------");

mCurrentLocation = mylocation;

LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(mlastLocation.getLatitude(),mlastLocation.getLongitude());
LatLng thisLatLng = new LatLng(mylocation.getLatitude(),mylocation.getLongitude());
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(lastLatLng).add(thisLatLng).width(20).color(Color.RED));
}
```

This is the output from logcat with last and current location [image]

and plotted route [image]

As you can see, the plotted line isnt continuous. Is there anything that I should change to make it work smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is using `getLastLocation()` as the other end of the line. Instead you should always remember the previous location that was received in `onLocationChanged()` and draw a line from the previous location to the latest location.

The "last location" is the best estimate of the current location and your `mCurrentLocation` also is the current location. Sometimes these two might be exactly the same and you would just draw dots instead of lines. Now, in real life they often vary a little so you get some lines that are not connected to each other. You are basically plotting the difference of the current location simply just received via `onLocationChanged()` and the current location estimated by the logic that's behind `getLastLocation()`.

Your code could be something like:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location mylocation) {

    logEvent("onLocationChanged");

    //mlastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mlastLocation = mCurrentLocation;
    mCurrentLocation = mylocation;
    if (mlastLocation != null) {
        plotroute(mylocation);      
    }           
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, when I change it like that, then i get null value at this line inside of plotroute method:         LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(mlastLocation.getLatitude(), mlastLocation.getLongitude());

Comment: Ah, sorry. When the code is ran for the first time `mCurrentLocation` is still `null` and so `mLastLocation` will be `null`. The code could check if `mCurrentLocation` is still `null` and in that case assign `myLocation` to it instead. Or you could choose not to call `plotroute()` if `mlastLocation` is null.

Comment: Ive created check like if (mlastLocation==null){
        mlastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }  and its fixed for now, although it has some glitches in that polyline [as you can see](http://i.imgur.com/ZKDLI8T.png)